# Update only not null fields

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

How to tell hibernate to not update fields with null values ?

I have filled entity (without password field which is not-null field). I want to update all filled fields in entity (skip the fields with null values) but I recive error like that:

```
by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint
```

How to tell hibernate to update ONLY changed fields (an skip all null values).

### Edit (code)

workerService:

```
public Worker updateWorker(Worker worker) { // only a few fields are filled.
     workerDao.update(worker);
     return worker;
}
```

and DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
abstract public class AbstractDao<T> {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

//....

public void update(T entity) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entity);
}
//...
```

WorkerEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "worker", schema = "public")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Worker implements java.io.Serializable {
```

Comment: can you share your code please

Comment: edit -> add code to post

Comment: did u get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic-update attribute tells Hibernate whether to include unmodified properties in the SQL UPDATE statement.

dynamic-update=true then only updated column will appear in update query

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test", catalog = "test_1")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
)
```

Comment: I have annotation @DynamicUpdate but it doesnt work.